# Some Column data is not displaying when data is retrieved using dapper

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core-mvc, dapper, npgsql

I wanted to retrieve data from a table using dapper and a query like this:

Controller:

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.accounts = GetAccountLists().OrderByDescending(x => x.AccountName).ToList();

        List<Transaction> transactionLists = new List<Transaction>();

         using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connString))
         {
             string query = "SELECT t.transaction_id, a.account_name, a.type, t.amount, t.date " +
                            "FROM account AS a " +
                            "INNER JOIN transaction AS t ON a.account_id = t.account_id;";

             List<Transaction> transactions = connection.Query<Transaction>(query) as List<Transaction>;
             transactionLists.AddRange(transactions);
        }

        var model = new TransactionViewModel();
        model.Transactions = transactionLists;

        return View(model);
    }
```

`TransactionViewModel`:

```
public class TransactionViewModel
{
    public List<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr">
            <th>Account</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>View</th>
        </thead>
        </tr>
        @foreach(var item in Model.Transactions)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.AccountName</td>
                <td>@item.Amount</td>
                <td>@item.Date</td>
                <td>@item.Type</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="window.location.href='/HOME/TransactionInfo?id=@item.TransactionId'">View details</button></td>
            </tr>
        }
      </table>
</div>
```

`Transaction` model class:

```
public class Transaction
{
    public int TransactionId { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public int Income { get; set; }
    public int Expense { get; set; }
}
```

In the end, I was able to display data of `Date`, `Amount`, `type` but getting null values at `Account Name` - what have I done wrong?

I am using Dapper for object mapping. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Well - in your SQL **query**, you're selecting `Account_Name` with an underscore - but your model class has `AccountName` *without* the underscore

How is Dapper supposed to be able to match those different names??

Possible solutions:

- Either use `Account_Name AS AccountName` in your SQL query
- or change the `AccountName` field of your `Transaction` class to `Account_Name`

Then you should get back the data as expected - the **names** (or aliases) of your SQL query and the field names of your class your mapping your data into **MUST MATCH** !